# Windows Print PDF with LPR from Command Line prints as text

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, command-line, lpr

When I try to print a PDF via lpr at the command prompt, the pdf is interpreted as text and garbage prints.

I have tried all of the following:

```
lpr -S PRINTSVR -P LP4081 c:\sample.pdf

lpr -S PRINTSVR -P LP4081 -ol c:\sample.pdf

lpr -S PRINTSVR -P LP4081 -o l c:\sample.pdf

lpr -S PRINTSVR -P LP4081 "-o l" c:\sample.pdf

lpr -o l -S PRINTSVR -P LP4081 c:\sample.pdf
```

How do I print a pdf from the command line using lpr in Windows?

Comment: I am also facing same problem, did you manage solve the issue?

Comment: I think this is a limitation of windows LPR.  I have not found a solution.  As a workaround, we pass PS files.